# Linux Mint Firefox branded version not abiding to configuration file

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint, administrator, deployment

I'm customizing a Linux Mint 19.3 installation for internal use and tried to configure Firefox's homepage in advance. This should (and indeed does in Ubuntu's version) work by customizing the preferences file in **/etc/firefox/syspref.js** as below:

```
lockPref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://<corporate URL>"); 
lockPref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", "<corporate proxy bypass list>")
```

The proxy configuration works as intended, but the homepage still ends up falling back to the Linux Mint default homepage. I understand this is done to help the developer of the distribution to monetize it (as described [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=282718)), but I really need it to be set to the corporate page.

When changing this setting on the user specific config file at **/home/{user}/.mozilla/firefox/{unique_id}.default/prefs.js** it successfully changes the homepage (and this is how its done by the browser's interface itself), but I need a solution independent of the end-user directory being configured/created or not.

The question is where is Mint setting the homepage (and if it is hardcoded in some way) and how can I change it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it! The custom preferences set in place by Linux Mint are described in **/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/distribution.ini** . Those gain preference even over those set in the **syspref.js**.

Additionally, I found out it's better to set those preferences I wanted to in a  **policies.json** on that same directory, as it's the proper 'corporate' way of setting up a Firefox pre-install.